# Multiply two unsigned 16 bit values, without using multiply or divide instructions [8086 Assembly]

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

I'm currently working on an assignment, where I write a subroutine where 2 unsigned numbers get multiplied and yield a result in the DX:AX pair. But i cannot use the instructions mul, imul, div, and idiv. When i run my code, the bottom half (the AX register) is always correct, but the DX register is not. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

```
;-----------------------------------------------------------
;
; Program:  MULTIPLY
;
; Function: Multiplies two 16 bit unsigned values ...
;           .... duplicating the MUL instruction
;
; Input:    The two values to be multiplied are passed on the stack
;           The code conforms to the C/C++ calling sequence
;
; Output:   The 32 bit result is returned in the dx:ax pair
;           Registers required by C/C++ need to be saved and restored
;
; Owner:    Andrew F.
;
; Changes:  Date        Reason
;           ------------------
;           07/20/2013  Original version
;
;
;---------------------------------------
         .model    small
         .8086
         public    _multiply

         .data
;---------------------------------------
; Multiply data
;---------------------------------------


         .code
;---------------------------------------
; Multiply code
;---------------------------------------
_multiply:                             
         push      bp                  ; save bp
         mov       bp,sp               ; anchor bp into the stack
         mov       ax,[bp+4]           ; load multiplicand from the stack
         mov       dx,[bp+6]           ; load multiplier   from the stack

    push    bx
    push    cx
    push    di
;---------------------------------------
; copy ax to cx, and dx to bx
;---------------------------------------  
    mov cx,ax       ;using bx and cx as my inputs
    mov bx,dx
;---------------------------------------
; Check for zeros, zero out ax and dx
;---------------------------------------  
start:
    xor   ax,ax         ; check for multiplication by zero
    mov   dx,ax         ; and zero out ax and dx
    mov   di,cx     ; 
    or    di,bx         ; 
    jz    done      ;
    mov   di,ax         ; DI used for reg,reg adc
;---------------------------------------
; loop / multiply algorithm
;---------------------------------------  
loopp:
    shr   cx,1          ; divide by two, bottom bit moved to carry flag
    jnc   skipAddToResult   ;no carry -> just add to result
    add   ax,bx     ;add bx to ax 
    adc   dx,di         ;add the carry to dx

skipAddToResult:
    add   bx,bx         ;double bx current value
    or    cx,cx         ; zero check
    jnz   loopp     ; if cx isnt zero, loop again


;---------------------------------------
; Restore register values, return
;---------------------------------------  
done:
     pop       di           ;restore di
     pop       cx           ;restore cx
     pop       bx           ;restore bx

         pop       bp                  ; restore bp
         ret                           ; return with result in dx:ax
                                       ;
         end                           ; end source code
;---------------------------------------
```

Comment: When doubling the `bx` you need to consider carry into `di` and you need to double `di` too. I suppose `adc di, di` would work. PS: learn to use a debugger so you can step through your code and see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are strangely using `di` when adding another shifted value of `bx`. Your algorithm seems to be like this:

1. Gather values, put them into BX and CX.
2. While CX>0:

   1. Shift CX rightwards.
   2. If shifted bit had a one, add BX to AX and add DI (there's zero in DI?) to DX with carry.
   3. Add BX to BX.
3. Return DX:AX.

You are missing a left-shift of DI:BX after each right shift of CX. You are shifting only BX (and I'd use `shl bx,1` instead of `add bx,bx`) while DI remains at zero, therefore when BX exceeds 16 bits, you lose bits that should go to DX. To remedy, use rotate through carry against DI.

```
loopp:
    shr   cx,1          ; divide by two, bottom bit moved to carry flag
    jnc   skipAddToResult   ;no carry -> just add to result
    add   ax,bx     ;add bx to ax 
    adc   dx,di         ;add the carry to dx

skipAddToResult:
    shl   bx,1         ;double bx current value
    rcl   di,1         ; and put overflow bits to DI
                       ; this together doubles the number in DI:BX
    or    cx,cx         ; zero check
    jnz   loopp     ; if cx isnt zero, loop again
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Vesper! That was the exact problem, and a quick and easy fix helped my code pass all of the test cases.

Comment: It's always better to use `test cx,cx` instead of `or cx,cx` ([for performance as well as human readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806)).  Also, `shl bx, 1` would be more efficient as `add bx,bx`, but `shl` is more clear for humans.

Comment: Also, you could use the ZF result of the shift as the loop-exit check if you duplicate the loop body for the final iteration.  (i.e. `shr cx,1` / `jnz loopp` to set up for the next iteration, or fall out of the loop with a potentially non-zero CF from the last bit).